# How to access two Mongo databases within one Angular application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb

At the moment I am running a MEAN stack application that is using one Mongo database called `mydb-1`.

I'm running this on localhost and on my command line, I am running the following:

`node bin\www --mongoURL mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb-1`

In addition to this Mongo database - `mydb-1` I now need to access another Mongo database called `mydb-2` within the same application.

Up until now, I have been using the above command line statement to access mydb-1.

What do I now need to do, inorder for my application to also see both mydb-1 and mydb-2 Mongo databases, when it comes to the command line, i.e.:

`node bin\www --mongoURL mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb-1, mydb-2`

At the moment, I am using the npm package express-mongo-db over at:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mongo-db

where my mongodb connection is made.

My code is similar to the following for one mongo database.

```
var app = require('express');

var expressMongoDb = require('express-mongo-db');
app.use(expressMongoDb('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb-1'));

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    req.db // => Db object
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to access it from the command line when you can create a node server file for the same? Any specific reason!

Comment: Yes you are correct but this was more to do with my localhost testing.

Comment: Did you try with Mongoose ODM?

Comment: @SaurabhGhewari Sorry but how would this help? Are you able to provide some further info pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do it with the **express-mongo-db** package you are using. As per its specification, it only supports connection made to just a particular database and not multiple one as you want to. Anyways, you can achieve this by using just the standard *mongodb* and *express* module, like so:

```
const app = require('express')();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// URL to the root of MongoDB Server and not a particular db
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Names
const dbName1 = 'myproject1';
const dbName2 = 'myproject2';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  console.log("Connected successfully to mongo server");

  const db1 = client.db(dbName1);
  const db2 = client.db(dbName2);

  app.get('/data/db1', function(req, res) {
    var collection = db1.get().collection('collectionName')

    collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
      res.render('dataPage', {dataFromDB1: docs})
    })
  });

  app.get('/data/db2', function(req, res) {
    var collection = db2.get().collection('collectionName')

    collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
      res.render('dataPage', {dataFromDB2: docs});
    });
  });

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000...')
})
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply. Just so that I understand, are you saying that Express js cannot handle multiple Mongo database connections for the one Angular app or have I misunderstood? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't say that an express app can't cater to your situation. I just said that the third party package you are using by the name **express-mongo-db** cannot solve your problem because as per its implementation it can only connect to a single database per express app. I already gave you the boilerplate code that would solve your problem. Please re-read my answer word to word and line by line. Let me know if you still have any doubts.

Comment: At the moment, it's looking good but I just want to ask you, instead of having both the routes within the same file as you have above, that is, `/data/db1` and `/data/db2`, I actually want to split these out to separate files. In doing this, I assume I need to replicate the MongoClient.connect(url) so that one url in file_1.js points to `mongodb://localhost:27017/db1` and the other url in file_2.js  points to `mongodb://localhost:27017/db2` with it's own MongoClient.connect(url) - is this correct or will this cause me problems? Thanks.

Comment: You can just create different files for each and a separate file for database connection and please don't make the connection to a specific database. DO NOT append the URL with the db name. just make connection to the root server `mongodb://localhost:27017` and not `mongodb://localhost:27017/db1` or  `mongodb://localhost:27017/db2`. I already mentioned it all in my answer. I request you to read it carefully.

Comment: Can you please explain why I shouldn't make the connection to the whole url within each separate file, i.e `mongodb://localhost:27017/db1` or `mongodb://localhost:27017/db2` What problems will this cause?

Comment: Can you please explain why do you need to create two different connections for two different database explicitly when you can do it by making just one root connection and access all the database thereafter?

Comment: I'm afraid to say but you actually have to re-write all your code related to database access because you are using some third party package that doesn't even cater to your specifications. You should hire some Technical Guide who can help you choose what technologies you need to start with to build your app.

Comment: All good - I really appreciate your help. I guess it's all part of the learning process.